# How do I map a vector of streams to peekables?

Tags: rust, async-await

I have N `futures::Stream` where each `Item` has a timestamp. I want to merge-sort them into a single stream, so I want to convert all streams to peekables:

```
fn merge_streams(
    mut streams: Vec<Box<dyn futures::Stream<Item = Data>>>,
) -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Data> {
    async_stream::try_stream! {
          let n = streams.len();
          let streams: Vec<_> = streams.into_iter().map(|s| s.peekable()).collect();
    }
}
```

I am stuck at this error:

```
error: the `peekable` method cannot be invoked on a trait object
     |
     |         let streams: Vec<_> = streams.into_iter().map(|s| s.peekable()).collect();
```

`peekable()` requires `Self: Sized`.

Does this mean `T.peekable()` and `Box<T>.peekable` requires to know `sizeof(T)` at compile time? If so, why? What is a workaround?

I tried

- `Vec<Box<dyn Stream>>`
- `Vec<Box<dyn Stream + Sized>>`
- `Vec<Box<_>>`
- `Vec<&mut dyn Stream>`
- `Vec<&mut dyn Stream + Sized>`

Comment: Also how is it possible that you accept many trait objects, but return a compile-time known type?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexLarionov why would that not be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BoxStream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/type.BoxStream.html) (easily created by [`StreamExt::boxed`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.boxed)):

```
use futures::{StreamExt, stream::BoxStream}; // 0.3.5

fn merge_streams(streams: Vec<BoxStream<()>>) {
    streams.into_iter().map(|s| s.peekable()).count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `peekable()` required `Pin<Box<..>> (=BoxStream)` not `Box<..>`